# How do I get html and javascript out of my ajax php function?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, coding-style

I just wrote some code, looked it over, and wanted to cry. Lines that end in .'\');">'; cannot be a good thing.

I'm writing an ajax function to return a new row to add to a table.  The row uses javascript to be user editable.

```
$ident=mysql_insert_id().'_c_label';

    $html='<tr>';
        $html.='<td class="label" id="'.$ident.'" onclick="editTextStart(\''.$ident.'\');">';
            $html.='<div>';
                $html.='<span id="'.$ident.'_field">'.self::default_label.'</span>';
                $html.='<input id="'.$ident.'_input" type=text onblur="editTextEnd(\''.$ident.'\');" onclick="editTextEnd(\''.$ident.'\');"/>';
            $html.='</div>';
        $html.='</td>';
        $html='<td>';
        $html.='</td>';
        $html='<td>';
        $html.='</td>';
        $html='<td>';
        $html.='</td>';
    $html.='</tr>';

    return $html;
```

So how should I be going about this to get html and javascript variables out of my php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an external JavaScript file, which you include with a `script` tag just before your closing `</body>` tag (or in the `head`, there are trade-offs — off-topic discussion of them below). You can hook up event handlers at that point by using DOM selectors and/or IDs and `attachEvent` (IE) or `addEventListener` (standard).

For instance, say your structure looks like this:

```
<table id='niftyStuff'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cool</td>
            <td>Stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cool</td>
            <td>Stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then with straight JavaScript+DOM methods, you can hook up a click handler to the cells like this:

```
var table, cells, index;
table  = document.getElementById('niftyStuff');
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (index = 0; index < cells.length; ++index) {
    hookEvent(cells.item(index), 'click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler() {
    // Handle the click; `this` will refer to the cell
}

// Convenience function defined somewhere to smooth out IE/Standards
function hookEvent(element, name, handler) {
    if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + name, handler);
    }
    else if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(name, handler, false);
    }
    else {
        throw "Unsupported browser";
    }
}
```

(Or you can define `hookEvent` in a way that only looks for which version to use once, but it would be over-complex for the example above.)

Off-topic, but if that `hookEvent` looks awkward,  a using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can really help smooth these browser differences out.

For instance, with jQuery:

```
$('#niftyStuff td').click(clickHandler);
function clickHandler() {
    // Handle the click; `this` will refer to the cell
}
```

(**Edit** Sounds from your comment below like you're using jQuery, so here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/oguso4) for the above.)

With Prototype:

```
$$('#niftyStuff td').invoke('observe', 'click', clickHandler);
function clickHandler() {
    // Handle the click; `this` will refer to the cell
}
```

**Off-topic**: I said above to put your `script` tag at the end of the body. That's just one choice. If you do, the DOM **will** reliably be ready to be searched, etc., you [don't have to wait](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) for `window.onload` which happens much, much later or rely on "ready" events. But if your script file isn't coming from the browser cache, there's a delay while your page may be showing (and your user clicking) before you hook things up. On the up side, your page displays more quickly (because the script file didn't hold things up by being in the `head`); on the downside, you probably don't want them frustrated by clicking before you're ready (although the gap is quite small). So where you put it is a balance between those things. If you're worried about people jumping on clicks, put the script in `head` but then have a small script tag at the end of `body` that calls a function defined in the file that hooks things up. Or use a `ready` event (most libraries provide them). Or there are sophisticated strategies to use a small inline script to capture and defer clicks.

Comment: I try to use external js files whenever possible.  But since this row is being dynamically generated, how can I hook it up in an external file?

Comment: @Matt: I find I can almost always hook things up by giving myself a few fixed points and then navigating from there. For instance, in the example I just added, the fixed point is the table, and then I navigate to the cells from there.

Comment: Ah thank you.  That jquery looks like what I want, assuming 'this' will actually refer to 'this'

Comment: @Matt: No problem. And yes, `this` will refer to the cell (the actual DOM element on which the handler was attached, which you can wrap in a jQuery instance if you like, or use "raw"). I've added a link to a live example to the answer (for convenience: http://jsbin.com/oguso4).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get the HTML ... out of my PHP", but something like this should be nicer:

```
$default_label = self::default_label;
$html = <<<HTML
<tr>
  <td class="label" id="$ident" onclick="editTextStart('$ident');">
    <div>
      <span id="{$ident}_field">{$default_label}</span>
      <input id="$ident_input" type=text onblur="editTextEnd('$ident')" onclick="editTextEnd('$ident');"/>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
HTML;

return $html;
```

Note that this uses [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which StackOverflow's parser can't cope with, hence the ugly formatting.

You could also move the inline Javascript calls into an external file by using `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, but this will be trickier if you are adding the content dynamically.